# Get user details with ClaimsPrincipal.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I am using azure active directory authentication to pull user information.

I am able to get user details using ClaimsPrincipal.Current. Is there any option to get Reporting Manage alias or name with this?

```
string userObjectID =
                ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make API calls to the Azure AD Graph API to get manager information.  More information on the AAD Graph APIs for working with users can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

Comment: any option with out graphapi?

Comment: @Kurkula none that I'm aware of.